# json.Unmarshal json string to object is empty result

Tags: json, object, go, marshalling

I've got a very simple program like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type RunCommand struct{
    level string `json:"level"`
    caller string `json:"caller"`
    msg string `json:"msg"`
    cmd string `json:"cmd"`
}

func main() {
    content := `{"level":"info","caller":"my.go:10","msg":"run","cmd":"--parse"}`
    runCommand := RunCommand{}
    e := json.Unmarshal([]byte(content), &runCommand)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unmarshal error")
    }
    fmt.Println(runCommand.level)
}
```

I wish that I could parse out all the json fields inside "content" into "runCommand" object, but actually, the final "fmt.Println" prints nothing. Where did I get wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have exported fields, like this:

```
type RunCommand struct{
    Level string `json:"level"`
    Caller string `json:"caller"`
    Msg string `json:"msg"`
    Cmd string `json:"cmd"`
}
```

and now you can use: `fmt.Println(runCommand.Level)` otherwise `json.Unmarshal` will ignore non-exported fields.